# Mandrill send email to multiple with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, email, mandrill

I am using Mandrill API to send email. I have a bunch of `@request.agents` (an array of Agent ID's) and I want to send all agents in the array the email.

This is my current method but it doesn't seem to be passing the `a` (I am aware that this may be completely the wrong approach)

```
def new_request_agents(request, user)

    @request = request
    @user = user

    template_name = "new-request"
    template_content = []
    message = {
        to: [
                request.agents.each do |a| 
                  if a != ""
                    {
                        email: Agent.find(a.to_i).email
                    }
                  end
                end
            ],
        subject: "New Request: #{user.email}",
        merge_vars: [
            {rcpt: @user.email,
            vars: [
                {name: "MESSAGE", content: request.message},
                {name: "AGENTS", content: request.agents}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    mandrill_client.messages.send_template template_name, template_content, message
end
```

Is there a better (and working) way of doing this?

**UPDATE**

My API log shows this:

```
{
"template_name": "new-request",
"template_content": {},
"message": {
    "to": [
        [
            "",
            "4",
            "5"
        ]
    ],
    "subject": "New Request: example@gmail.com",
    "merge_vars": [
        {
            "vars": [
                {
                    "name": "MESSAGE",
                    "content": "Test message"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AGENTS",
                    "content": [
                        "",
                        "4",
                        "5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"async": false,
"ip_pool": null,
"send_at": null,
"key": "B-B_-yRi1LLLhBrzZEVLLw"
```

}

Comment: Please make sure `message` is correct by doing: `message.inspect`

Comment: Is your problem that the resulting `message` object does not contain what you want it to contain, or is everything in there as expected, but Mandrill does the wrong thing with it?

Comment: @janfoeh my problem is that It wont send at all. I am getting a `Couldn't find Agent with id=` error. I think my use of an each loop is the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove `rcpt` from `merge_vars` because there is more than one recipient.

And make sure `message` does contain all your emails by doing: `message.inspect`.

An other good practice is looking at API logs in your mandrill dashboard. There is always useful informations.

Update:

Try this

```
request.agents.each do |a| 
  {
    email: a.email
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. It just looks like `a` is not being passed in the loop as I am getting a `Couldn't find Agent with id=` am I doing this the right way with an each loop?

Comment: What does `a` contain? It seems that it doesn't contain an ID so you can't use it with `find`. If it contains an email you can do what I wrote in my post.

Comment: `a` is actually only an array of numbers which are the ID's of the agents. I have added in my API log in an update. Looks like it's not requesting it correctly as the emails are just coming up as numbers. I added in a `if a != ""` as it looks like the first array value was blank and thats why I was getting the original error